# How do I resolve a self signed certificate error?

Tags: http, firefox, ssl-certificate

I have a website and I'm trying to visit it from Firefox and I get this error:

`Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`

The certificate viewer says "Could not verify this certificate because the issuer is unknown"

Is my error caused just because I don't have a proper SSL certificate?

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of this error you need to make your site certificate trusted on your client browser. You have two options for this:

1. A typical OS comes with popular trusted roots (root certificates) of some companies. E.g my MAC has preinstalled Amazon, Apple, DigiCert, Visa and so on root certificates. If you enrol https server certificate for your site from a famous company - it will be trusted on most of the systems.
2. Download your site's self-signed certificate and install it to trusted roots on your system registry - you make it trusted this way.